# How to make a selected dropdown option sticky?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am having problem with sticking the selected option in the drop-down menu in classic asp. If I keep "selected" as shown below, the options values keep on changing in the drop-down bar up to the end of the record in drop-down. In other words, it doesn't matter what you select from the option, it will eventually select the last option in the drop-down list. however it display the correct result. i.e it is selecting properly and working fine but doesn't stick on the selected option. Do you think I kept "selected" in wrong spot?

```
Select: <select class=input>
    <OPTION value=0>-- SELECT --</OPTION>
    <% dim rs
        SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(brand) as brand FROM tbl"
            SET rs=objConn.Execute(SQL)  

            IF NOT (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) THEN 
                WHILE NOT rs.EOF
                    Response.Write "<option selected value=""" & replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") & """>" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
                    rs.MoveNext
                WEND 
            END IF
                rs.close
                SET rs = nothing
        %>
    </select>
```

Comment: It's not your selected option it's your loop. You will need to write a bit more code to make your selected brand sticky. Your example OPTION value=0 gives me the impression you're working with an integer but your value= replace & with @ looks like you're using a string. What is the datatype from your SQL for table brand?

Comment: @MurrayW: Ya the options are string i.e name of the brands. I did OPTION value=0  so that the very first one should be default "Selected".

Comment: Ok, I wrote you some code and posted it. Should work, if it gives you any issues I'll help with the debug but it should work with a simple copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because in your loop you are setting every option to "selected" and the browser will default to the last option in the list that has that designation.
You need to decide which one you want selected and only include "selected" in that option.  If you want the first one (the one you created outside the loop), just don't use "selected" at all.

For example, if you want the brand "Acme" to be selected, do this:

```
  dim strQueryBrand
  If Request.QueryString("brandID") <> "" Then
     'add some validation here to avoid cross-site scripting issues'
     strQueryBrand = Request.QueryString("brandID")
  End
  dim isSelected = ""
   IF NOT (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) THEN 
        isSelected = ""
        If LCase(strQueryBrand) = LCase(strBrand) then
            isSelected = "selected "
        End If
        WHILE NOT rs.EOF
            Response.Write "<option " & isSelected & "value=""" & replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") & """>" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
            rs.MoveNext
        WEND 
    END IF
```

Comment: When I don't keep selected inside the loop, it just select the default option i.e "SELECT" it doesn't stick any brand at all

Comment: @VicStat If you want it to "stick" to a brand, you need to pick one, and only include "selected" in that `<option>` tag

Comment: VicStat needs to see how to select the brand. You setup a static selection. The OP querystring is dynamic. test.asp? list=bybrand & brandID= .Simply add the request.querystring like I posted in my answer and place the bundle within the loop. Outside of the loop can not select the correct option.

Comment: @MurrayW - I see, I missed that VicStat was redirecting onchange.  I thought he just wanted to choose one to pre-select.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @JenR: When I used " If LCase(strQueryBrand) = LCase(strBrand) then ", I found out my brand name (which got upper case name and lower case name) gets messed up. The options i.e brand names are not in alphabetical order any more. In other words, the brand names with lower cases lists (alphabetically) first then only the uppercase without worrying about alphabetical order. I don't know if it is because of using LCase(strQueryBrand) = LCase(strBrand)

Comment: @VicStat  That `if` statement only tests to see if strQueryBrand and strBrand contain the same value.  It would not change the order of anything.  It would ignore any inconsistant capitalization (so "FooBar" and "foobar" and "FOOBAR" would be treated as equal).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I've looked at ASP - but at first glance it appears that you are setting every option to be selected.

The following doesn't really make sense because you are telling each option that it is the selected one.  Ultimately the last option will be the selected one, because it was the one most recently told to be selected.

```
<select class=input>
    <option selected value="1">1</option>
    <option selected value="2">2</option>
    <option selected value="3">3</option>
    <option selected value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Your completed select should only have one option using the "selected" attribute

```
<select class=input>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option selected value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to write your output. 
I'm guessing you're using a string but brandID gives me the impression and your default value being numeric I'm thinking integer. 
In any case, follow the following to select your "Selected".

```
Select: <select class=input onChange="if(options[selectedIndex].value != 0){location='test.asp?list=bybrand&brandID=' + options[selectedIndex].value + '', exit=false;}">
    <% dim rs,strBrand,strQueryBrand
    If Request.QueryString("brandID") <> "" Then
    strQueryBrand = Request.QueryString("brandID")
      If InStr(strQueryBrand,"@") >= 1 Then
         strQueryBrand = Replace(strQueryBrand,"@"," & ")
      End If
    Else
    strQueryBrand = 0
    End If
    '# clean strQueryBrand to prevent SQL injection
        SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(brand) as brand FROM tbl"
            SET rs=objConn.Execute(SQL)  
            IF NOT (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) THEN 
        If strQueryBrand = 0 Then
        Response.Write "<OPTION value=0 selected>-- SELECT --</OPTION>"
        End If
                WHILE NOT rs.EOF
                strBrand = rs("brand") 
                If LCase(strQueryBrand) = LCase(strBrand) Then
                    Response.Write "<option selected value=""" & replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") & """>" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
                Else            
                    Response.Write "<option value=""" & replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") & """>" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
                End If
                rs.MoveNext
                WEND 
            END IF
                rs.close
                SET rs = nothing
        %>
    </select>
```

If it is a numeric value you are working with replace the following .

```
If LCase(strQueryBrand) = LCase(strBrand) Then
```

with

```
If (cInt(strQueryBrand) - cInt(strBrand)) = 0 Then
```

Added another method using **PART** of Jen R answer. 
    If you have dynamic changing selection content you must make the selection within the loop or it's simply STATIC one answer then you wouldn't need to worry about the Selected because it would be the same each and every time.

```
Select: <select class=input onChange="if(options[selectedIndex].value != 0){location='test.asp?list=bybrand&brandID=' + options[selectedIndex].value + '', exit=false;}">
<% dim rs,strBrand,strQueryBrand,isSelected
    If Request.QueryString("brandID") <> "" Then
    strQueryBrand = Request.QueryString("brandID") 
      If InStr(strQueryBrand,"@") >= 1 Then
         strQueryBrand = Replace(strQueryBrand,"@"," & ")
      End If
    Else
    strQueryBrand = 0
    End If
'# clean strQueryBrand to prevent injection
    SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(brand) as brand FROM tbl"
        SET rs=objConn.Execute(SQL)  

        IF NOT (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) THEN 
        If strQueryBrand = 0 Then
        Response.Write "<OPTION value=0 selected>-- SELECT --</OPTION>"
        End If
            WHILE NOT rs.EOF
            strBrand = rs("brand") 
            If LCase(strQueryBrand) = LCase(strBrand) Then
                isSelected = "selected "
            End If           
                Response.Write "<option "&isSelected&" value=""" & replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") & """>" & rs("brand") & "</option>"

            rs.MoveNext
            WEND 
        END IF
            rs.close
            SET rs = nothing
    %>
</select>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. However, is it still possible to keep a default selection i.e "SELECT" when the page loads initially? because it is empty right now

Comment: Yes, if your default is 0 then the strQueryBrand string should be set to zero. I'll update the code to show how you could do it with either example.

Comment: Updated the code, if your QueryString("brandID") returns NULL or Empty it will default to the SELECT option. This should be very typical for first page load.

Comment: @VicStat I just noticed we all have a common mistake in our examples. Your replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") needs to be reversed if we are going to match your brand data. Not sure why you are replacing the & with @ but I'm updating to cover this oversight.

Comment: I am not sure if I should ask it over here again. Actually, in this project, I need to have two drop-down controls and in both, the options need to be sticky once selected. I did not mention it in my original question thinking that is it going to be same, if it works for one drop-down, it will definitely work for another too. So my main point is: when I select one option in one drop-down and then select on the other, the sticky option in first one goes away. i.e it just sticks an option for only one drop-down at a time. Can you please tell why is this? I need to stick selected options on both.

Comment: @VicStat we all need you to search "How to create multiple select form". It's really easy once you know the basics. Your issue is because you are reusing your querystring BrandID If you have two or more forms rename the input names so they are unique or give your form an ID. You'll know what I am talking about once you build a few forms. We all had to learn HTML which is your new question. "Form Select options with GET". It's easy, you'll learn it fast, and to think, I just gave you the answer... again.

Comment: I will do that for sure. Thanks @Murray and all who tried to help me